# best way to maintain properties files in spring mvc application

Tags: java

In my Spring MVC application application we are maintaining many configuration files like `.properties` and `.txt` files. I want to read all configuration files and keep them in application context level, so that I can access configuration data in my entire application.

Example:

1. db.properties

   ```
   db.driveClassName=packages.DataSource
   db.URL=some url....
   ```
2. errorCodes.properties

   ```
   <error-code>=<error description>

   ERR001=time out error occured
   ERR002=The request was tampered
   ERR003=transaction id is missing
   ```

Comment: you can connect all the properties files by adding annotations.

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to use @ConfigurationalProperties then they are type safe and you can even validate them look at this guide http://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot